# Java map with 2D boolean array as values

Tags: java, dictionary

Hello suppose I have a hashmap

`HashMap<Integer,boolean[][]> map= new HashMap();`

How do I put a true or false value on the map in the 2d array

Comment: HashMap or 2D array? What do you want¿?

Comment: 2d array on hashmap, I edited it to show what I want

Comment: Maybe both?  Like a Map<KeyType, Boolean[][]> ?  I don't really understand the question either.

Comment: @Steffan Harris- I don't see what the advantage is to storing a Boolean[][] over a boolean[][].  Can you clarify what it is that you're trying to do and why a raw boolean[][] isn't sufficient?

Comment: So, it's more like a 3D array. (The Map introduces another dimension.) This is quite an awkward data structure, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap<Integer, boolean[][]> map = new HashMap();
int rowNumber = 1;
boolean[][] array2D = map.get(rowNumber);
array2D[10][20] = true;
```

Comment: Small point, but you can't put booleans into a Map, only Booleans

Comment: @britishmutt- You can't booleans into a Map because they're primitive, but you *can* put boolean[][]s into a Map because arrays are indeed objects.

Comment: Oh yeah!  I forgot about that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//First get the boolean array if it exists.
boolean[][] value = map.get(key);
//If it doesn't exist in the map yet, instantiate it.
if(value == null){
  value = new boolean[size1][size2];
  map.put(key,value);
}
//Set the boolean value in the array at the correct location
value[index1][index2] = booleanValue;
```

Fill in the key, booleanValue, sizes, and indices as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you want to put straight up boolean values in the map.  The way you have it set up, your map is not made up of booleans, but actually of boolean arrays.

That's why you can't just put `map.put(key, true)` because `true` is not of the type `boolean[][]`, it is just a plain vanilla boolean.  You will probably get a type mismatch error of some kind because `boolean`s can't just magically become arrays unless you tell the computer where to put the boolean in your array.

If you actually meant to make a map where each bucket holds a 2D array, then rfeak's answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
int index, row, col = ....
Boolean[][] array = map.get(index);
array[row][col] = true/false;
```

Comment: I want to put a value on the map

Comment: So you want to do map.put (index, array)?  Maybe I still don't understand your question.

Comment: WHy can't I use map.put() to put my true or false value on the map?

Comment: Using map.put() would completely discard any array that happened to be associated with the given key.  Java isn't sensitive to the fact that the value type is an array and that you just want to write a single value; to do this you'd need to look up the array associated with the key and then set the value at the appropriate spot, as shown by britishmutt's answer.

Comment: @Steffan: because the values in your map have to be boolean[][] arrays, not single boolean values.  Even if you could, how would the map know where in the array to put your boolean value anyway?